# Batch program to automatically sort zip files into folders and extract

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, extract

I am a teacher aid, and my job is to sort student's labs into their folders. The format they turn in their files is like this

**lastname_Labname.zip**

What I wish to accomplish is to automatically have these zips moved into their folders in a different location. Which follows this format

- Lastname1
- Lastname2
- Lastname3

Finally I would like the zip files to be deleted after.

Here is what I have so far:

To extract the files:

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
pushd %CD%
cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
        "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X"
pause
    )
popd
)
```

To sort the files:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Something\Something"
SET "destdir=C:Somethign\Something"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.zip" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=_-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*%%b*" '
  ) DO (
    MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\" 

  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I would like to combine these functions, and to delete the zips after.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, this website isn't a free coding service. You need to show us _some_ effort.

Comment: This should get you there... https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: @MattBall - Looks like some code's been added now.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup.

```
@Echo OFF
set Down=E:\Download
set Extracted=E:\Extracted

for /R "%Down%" %%I in ("*.zip") do (

  "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y "%%~fI" -pPasswordGoesHere
  Del "%%I"

)
FOR    %%i IN ("%Down%\*") DO MOVE /Y "%%i" "%Sorted%\%%~nxi" /xf Unzip.bat
FOR /D %%i IN ("%Down%\*") DO ROBOCOPY /MOVE /E "%%i" "%Sorted%\%%~nxi" /xf Unzip.bat
```